# Compiling for execution under JRE 6 with Maven

Tags: java, maven, compatibility

I have a requirement to compile an app for use under JRE 6.
Initially the app was compiled for use under JRE 8.

So I added:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

to pom.xml

After fixing all the errors caused by unavaiable diamond operator, string in switch statement etc. I ran the app under JRE 6 and got the error.

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/nio/file/Paths
```

Ok. This class is available only since Java 7. But the question arises: what does the above maven setting exactly? Does it only check the syntax? If so, then it's not quite useful.

What needs to be done to configure maven so that it notifies me about missing classes in particular Java version too?

Answer (score 2):

[`java.nio.file.Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html) was introduced in Java 7. You will have to change the implementation of your code to only use classes available in Java 6.

And yes, the Maven property only tells `javac` to use Java 6 syntax. That's very useful. Maven will not magically change your code for you. `javac` started by `mvn package` will tell you about unresolveable imports.

Comment: Edited again. `javac` tells you.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is the correct answer and it should be marked as one

Comment: 'mvn package' doesn't prevent the app from successful build

Comment: I've just inserted import java.util.Objects; (which exists only since Java 7) and run the build. No errors.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose is to instruct maven to pass the -source and -target to the javac compile executable. It makes sure you only use language features that are available in the given JRE (the diamond operator is a great example), but it does not prevent use of APIs that only came along later.

[Have a read of this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

In particular the part at the bottom of the page:

> Merely setting the target option does not guarantee that your code actually runs on a JRE with the specified version. The pitfall is unintended usage of APIs that only exist in later JREs...

I think it's unfair to say the parameters are not useful they certainly are. But they are not magical tools that know which libraries may be available at runtime.

Comment: Ok. As far as I understand there is no way to build and get all the warnings without installing that particular JDK (in my case 6) and set it up in Maven?

Comment: You are absolutely correct. 

If it finds the included library on the classpath or in the JDK libs folder, it will happily compile. Otherwise, you will get your errors.

On a side note, I believe java.nio classes are in rt.jar. There is a decent chance that copying rt.jar from your JDK7+ libs folder to your JDK6 libs folder will work. I wouldn't recommend it, and it wasn't your question. Just mentioning it though in case you felt like experimenting and it could solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

The Animal Sniffer plugin for maven verifies that classes compiled with a newer JDK/API are compatible with an older JDK/API.

https://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out how to do it.

You don't have to install the target JDK or JRE. All you need is **rt.jar** from that JRE.
Then you have to set the path to the jar file in **bootclasspath** in pom.xml.

```
<build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <verbose />
                    <bootclasspath>C:/data/tmp/rt.jar</bootclasspath>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```